# How to organize the jars in a central repository?

Tags: java

I have prepared some jars providing some common services for the applications of my company. Now i need to host these jars in a central repository by the version wise. So that the developers can utilize these services. How can i approach it.

Comment: Go through this guide. It will explain how to publish artifacts on Central repository. https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: its really helpful. Thank you so much

Comment: very good , Perfect :)